# Taxonomy/relationship model between frameworks and programming languages

Tags: frameworks, programming-languages

I plan to develop an algorithm that detects the similarity between a person's technical skills (e.g. Java, C++, Jenkins, etc.) and the technical requirements for a project. I figured it might be a problem if the requirement is something like React and the person has something like Angular as a skill. This person should not have zero simularity as Angular and React are both frontend frameworks based on html, css and javascript/typescript.

Is there a relationship model or taxonomy that shows the connection between programming languages and frameworks?

Thanks in advance.